# Spring @PostMapping throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, postman, spring-restcontroller

My REST controller looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/foos/sendSomeEmail")
    public void sendSomeEmail(@RequestParam(value = "fromDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime fromDate) {
        if (fromDate == null) {
            fromDate = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(7);
        }
        service.sendSomeEmail(fromDate);
    }
```

I am getting following exception while making POST request using Postman: `[0m[0m09:08:59,938 INFO  [stdout] (Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@2d0411f1]-1) org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported`

Postman Screenshot:
[image]

Can anyone help me to sort it out?

**UPDATE:** after I removed `@RequestParam`, the exception is still present.

```
@PostMapping("/foos/sendSomeEmail")
        public void sendSomeEmail() {

             LocalDateTime fromDate = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(7);

            service.sendSomeEmail(fromDate);
        }
```

Comment: Could it be the fact that you have `GET parameters` in the URL for `POST` request? Also @RequestParam instead of @BodyParam ?

Comment: Are you using the Java 8 Time modules for Jackson?That could be one of the problems.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: @George, nope. But, I guess, it would throw different type of exception, like ConversionFailedException or another one. Also, as you can see RequestParam is optional here, so after I remove it the exception is still present.

Comment: @dbl, I agree with you regarding '@RequestParam'.  Anyway, it is optional, and if I remove it, the exception is still present.

Comment: The annotation is set to "/foos/sendSomeEmail", but in the SS the URL is "services/foos/sendSomeEmail". Is there a mismatch there?

Comment: Do you expect to hit this mapping via an http POST or GET?

Comment: @George, my base url equals 'services' so it is correct.

Comment: @JonSampson, I am expecting POST, since service logic will create and store new entities.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your settings in the Postman user interface, the application is performing a GET on your mapping and thus you're receiving that exception.

Testing where the URI includes GET parameters (`fromDate=...`) seems to be overriding your POST selection. You'll note the `method` on line 643 of your screenshot denotes GET.

You should remove the parameter from the URI and use Postman to provide values via POST, which I believe you will find the ability to do elsewhere in the interface.